# Comparing to see if two functions are the same

Tags: hypothesis-testing, equivalence

I need help with something.

I need to see if two "sides" of data have/come from the same functional format. Consider a large sample with values from, let's say, 1 to 10. What I want to know is if the sample from 1-5 has the same functional format as the sample from 5-10. Maybe something like the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test but not for densities.

I know I would have to look at the derivatives, but I don't know where to start. Any help is appreciated

Thanks in advance